# British pronunciation of the word "year"

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

It's clear that this word is usually pronounced /jɪə/, but it seems to me that in some British accents (probably one of them is RP) it's pronounced /jeə/ so that it becomes a homophone of ‘yeah’.

Unfortunately, googling that gave no results, neither did I find such transcription in the dictionaries, but I hear it on [Youglish](https://youglish.com/pronounce/year/english/uk) very well: see examples 1, 4, 8, 9, 10 and 11 (the Queen).

*So the question is: is this pronunciation really valid?*

P.S. My mum was also taught this pronunciation in an English school when she was a child.

Answer (score 1):

Twenty years ago or so, the main RP pronunciation according to *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* was /jɪə/ (80 %  against 20 %  /jɜː/); /jeə/ is not recorded in this dictionary, which was then a leading dictionary in the domain of the pronunciation of English.  Here can be heard that predominant form: [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/year). In fact, except for the rhoticity, the American version is the same.

Comment: @PeterShor No, not a long i, but a diphthong, as in "here", "ear", "leer", "pier" (/ɪə/, BrE).  In AmE the second sound is less prominent or possibly long i with an r at the end (from the sample).